# Jump between view and view model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mvvm, resharper

Is there a way to make Resharper or "just" Visual Studio (perhaps using a macro) jump between the view and the it's view model in the MVVM pattern.

Like Resharper can jump between the xaml and it's codebehind using F7 and Shift-F7

I follow the convention that the files are located like this

\Views\name\AbcView.xaml
\ViewModels\name\AbcViewModel.xaml

Comment: F7 and Shift-F7 are key-gestures from VisualStudio, not from ReSharper, as far as I know

Comment: I don't know really but I like to use the "recent File" view (out-of-the box mapping for me is Ctrl-,)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I should have googled first, [here](http://www.alteridem.net/2008/02/26/visual-studio-macro-to-switch-between-cpp-and-h-files/) is a macro to do the same thing for .cpp and. .h files

I changed it a bit and assigned the macro to Ctrl+F7. Seems to work fine

```
Public Sub SwitchBetweenViewAndViewModel()
    '=====================================================================  
    ' If the currently open document is a view or viewmodel, attempts to  
    ' switch between them
    '=====================================================================  
    Dim currentDocument As String
    Dim targetDocument As String

    currentDocument = ActiveDocument.FullName

    If currentDocument.ToLower().Contains("\views\") And _
       (currentDocument.EndsWith("View.xaml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Or _
        currentDocument.EndsWith("View.xaml.cs", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
        targetDocument = currentDocument
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace(".xaml.cs", "")
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace(".xaml", "")
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace("\Views\", "\ViewModels\")
        targetDocument = targetDocument + "Model.cs"
    ElseIf currentDocument.ToLower().Contains("\viewmodels\") And currentDocument.EndsWith(".cs", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        targetDocument = currentDocument
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace("\ViewModels\", "\Views\")
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace("ViewModel.cs", "View.xaml")
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(targetDocument) Then
        OpenDocument(targetDocument)
    End If
End Sub

'=====================================================================  
' Given a document name, attempts to activate it if it is already open,  
' otherwise attempts to open it.  
'=====================================================================  
Private Sub OpenDocument(ByRef documentName As String)
    Dim document As EnvDTE.Document
    Dim activatedTarget As Boolean
    activatedTarget = False

    For Each document In Application.Documents
        If document.FullName = documentName And document.Windows.Count > 0 Then
            document.Activate()
            activatedTarget = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not activatedTarget Then
        Application.Documents.Open(documentName, "Text")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For VisualStudo > 2012 Macros are not available by default. Here is an extension: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/05/11/macros-extension-open-sourced-in-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 1):

What if more than one ViewModels are releated to the same View? :)

U may simply use `DesignInstance` markup extension to get R# navigation and code completion in binding work well:

```
namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModels
{
  public class PersonViewModel
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age     { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And the corresponding view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.PersonView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PersonInfo" Height="300" Width="300"

        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"

        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vms:PersonViewModel}">

  <UniformGrid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Age" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Age}" />
  </UniformGrid>

</Window>
```

Now R# can verify all the references to **ViewModel** properties in bindings, help you to complete property names and also can navigate directly to this properties. Moreover, all the code above is quickly baked using the R# **Specify DataContext type in ...** quick fix (at unresolved binding expressions).

p.s. **View** still have no dependency on **ViewModel** because all design-time attributes will be removed after compilation (by `mc:Ignorable="d"` attribute).

Comment: `{d:DesignerInstance}`/`{d:DesignData}` is supported only by R# 6.0, but early versions can infer `DataContext` type in other scenarios, like binding to resources or to other element by `ElementName`.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Karstens answer I changed the sub that switches in between files to both being able to switch in between **.cpp and .h files**, as well as **View and View Model files**.

If you want to do the same, follow [the instructions in his link](http://www.alteridem.net/2008/02/26/visual-studio-macro-to-switch-between-cpp-and-h-files/) but use this sub instead:

```
'=====================================================================  
' If the currently open document is a CPP or an H file, attempts to  
' switch between the CPP and the H file.  
'
' If the currently open document is a View.xml or an ViewModel.cs file, attempts to  
' switch between the View and the ViewModel file.  
'=====================================================================  
Sub SwitchBetweenAssociatedFiles()
    Dim currentDocument As String
    Dim targetDocument As String

    currentDocument = ActiveDocument.FullName

    If currentDocument.EndsWith(".cpp", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        targetDocument = Left(currentDocument, Len(currentDocument) - 3) + "h"
    ElseIf currentDocument.EndsWith(".h", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        targetDocument = Left(currentDocument, Len(currentDocument) - 1) + "cpp"
    ElseIf currentDocument.EndsWith("View.xaml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        targetDocument = currentDocument.Replace("\Views\", "\ViewModels\")
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace("\View\", "\ViewModel\")
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace("View.xaml", "ViewModel.cs")
    ElseIf currentDocument.EndsWith("ViewModel.cs", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        targetDocument = currentDocument.Replace("\ViewModels\", "\Views\")
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace("\ViewModel\", "\View\")
        targetDocument = targetDocument.Replace("ViewModel.cs", "View.xaml")
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(targetDocument) Then
        OpenDocument(targetDocument)
    End If

End Sub
```

I assigned it to **Alt + §** which was free in my configuration. Handy next to **Alt + Tab**. ^_^