# Shortcut between view and viewmodel (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, mvvm, visual-studio-2012

I am using the MVVM pattern and I am looking for a shortcut to switch between the viewmodel I am working on (*\viewmodel\*viewmodel.cs) and its corresponding view (*\view\*view.xaml), and vice versa.

I found a good solution to this at first, [Jump between view and view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318985/jump-between-view-and-view-model), but the answer is based on macros. In Visual Studio 2012 there doesn't seem to be any support for macros.

Any suggestions on how to solve this in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an Add-in will work. Check out Kyralessa's answer here:

[Alternative to macros in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027485/alternative-to-macros-in-visual-studio-2012)